# What is the marker attribute for the 'interior' edge?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

What is the attribute for a matplotlib marker that controls the interior ring like those shown in the example.  I would like the face color to be uniform (i.e., without the ring). I have never had this happen with a scatter plot before.

[image: marker example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting `linewidths=0` your problem might be solved.
I have put three examples in this code using `plt.scatter()`. Check them out.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 40)
y = np.random.normal(0, 5, 40)

plt.scatter(x, y, s=500, marker='o', alpha=0.5, color='b', linewidths=0) # s defines the size.
#plt.scatter(x, y, s=500, marker='o', alpha=0.5, color='b', linewidths=4)
#plt.scatter(x, y, s=500, marker='o', alpha=0.5, color='b', facecolor='red', edgecolor='black', linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: yep thank you the first option worked.  I haven't had to set linewidths before and assumed it did not apply to a marker.  Anyway, thanks again.